# I need help UITableView on UIView (Storyboard Project)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uistoryboard

I have one project using storyboard. I have one `UIView` and I put some images and buttons on view also at bottom I placed a `UITableView`. I put this code in `UIView.h`.

```
interface MenuViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

IBOutlet UITableView *MenuTable;

NSMutableArray *TabloMenu;
id menuler;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *MenuTable;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *TabloMenu;
```

And in `iuview.m`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)table {

 return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [TabloMenu count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellFirmalar";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         menuler = [TabloMenu objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [menuler objectForKey:@"Tanim"];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *alertString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clicked on row #%d", [indexPath row]];

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertString message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

Until here everything is working well. Data is coming when I click cell row number is showing.
I added new `UITableViewController` on storyboard and linked tableview to `UITableViewController` for segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Records"]){

        ResultTableViewController *cvc = (ResultTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

But it is not switching this. How can I will switch this `UITableViewController`? Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you just want to push a new table view controller when a cell from the first table is selected, all you're missing is that you need to have

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Records"];
```

in your tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: No visible @interface for 'MenuViewController' declares the selector 'performSegueWithIdentifier:'

Comment: pardon me, the method is performSegueWithIdentifier:sender.

Comment: so the call should look like
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Records" sender:self];

Comment: :( is not working alert is showing but not switching do you know another solution ?

Comment: how do you have the segue set up in storyboard? is it going from a table cell to the next view controller or is it going from the first view controller to the next view controller?

Comment: make the segue run from the first view controller to the second view controller, make sure that you have set the identifier to @"Records", and then try the call [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Records" sender:self]; again. It should work. But the controller has to be the sender (i.e., the point of origination for the segue).

Comment: yes if i run from uiview to second uitableview it work :) thanks a lot for all